# Looking for RSA C bare-metal implementation (for STM32)

Tags: cryptography, rsa, stm32

I'm looking for a bare-metal C implementation of RSA signature verification. If possible I need an implementation without dynamic allocation. The target is STM32H753.

I know there is a crypto library from STMicro providing RSA but source code is not available and anyway it doesn't seem available for STM32H7.

I had a look on github but it's hard to assess the projects quality.

EDIT: according to STMicro support there is a cryptolib patch to use it on STM32H7

Comment: Please read the [help] and [ask]:
*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ARM Mbed TLS: https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/encrypt-and-decrypt-with-rsa

Source code: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls

[License file](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/LICENSE) shows it is open source Apache 2.0.

I've used this library for SHA-256 hashing before on an STM32 mcu (withOUT using Mbed--its just a library after-all) and it worked great. (4 examples of doing the SHA-256 hash: https://os.mbed.com/teams/mbed-os-examples/code/mbed-os-example-tls-hashing/file/c68a6dc8d494/main.cpp/)

Comment: Srm32 crypto lib?

Answer (score 4):

STM32 has no hardware RSA support (only DES and AES), but any plain C software implementation would work. If you are unsure of the quality of a library, [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask about a *specific* library.

There is a hardware random number generator, which you can use e.g. instead of the `rand()` library function. Mind the recommended clock settings in the *Entropy source validation* chapter of the Reference Manual.